# Ruby Class, I suspect I am doing instance markers wrong

Tags: ruby, debugging, class, instance-variables

I want this class to initialize to receive a message to be saved and enter a filename for it. Am I drawing up an error because Ruby only wants values to be instantiated in the init method? Be gentle, I'm new to this. Traceback pasted below.

```
class DobbsyKretts
  idea = 'arbitaryvalue'
  def initialize
    #Receive idea
    puts "Enter an idea, a secret or anything else you want to encrypt. Hit enter to stop typing and save the file"
    @idea.gets.reverse.upcase
    #Filename and saving - to encrypt the file.
    puts "Enter the file name you'd like to have this saved as. Type PLAN at the beginning for plans and REM for reminders"
    @file_name.gets.strip
    File::open("DobbsyKrett-"+ file_name + ".txt", "w") do |f|
      f>>@idea
    end
  end
end

something = DobbsyKretts.new
```

Traceback:

```
testy.rb:11:in `initialize': private method `gets' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from testy.rb:21:in `new'
    from testy.rb:21:in `<main>'
Enter an idea, a secret or anything else you want to encrypt. Hit enter to stop typing and save the file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `gets`on `@idea` before having assigned a value - that's one of the reasons why you get the error. Also, gets should not be called on the instance variable here. Try it like this:

```
class DobbsyKretts
  def initialize
    #Receive idea
    puts "Enter an idea, a secret or anything else you want to encrypt. Hit enter to stop typing and save the file"
    (@idea = gets).reverse.upcase
    #Filename and saving - to encrypt the file.
    puts "Enter the file name you'd like to have this saved as. Type PLAN at the beginning for plans and REM for reminders"
    @file_name = gets.strip
    File::open("DobbsyKrett-"+ @file_name + ".txt", "w") do |f|
      f << @idea
    end
  end
end

something = DobbsyKretts.new
```

This works as you expected, but I just would like to remind you that it is a very bad idea to do something like this in the constructor. You should rather use a dedicated method for generating files and/or asking the user for input.

Comment: You say gets should NOT be called on the instance variable here... Why's that? And do you not  do it in the sixth line with added parentheses?

Comment: You're welcome! I call gets as a global function, it's not someobject.gets as in your example. Calling it globally ensures that the input is read from $stdin. You can however call gets on instances of IO (e.g. a File).

Comment: @emboss Assigning `@idea='arbitaryvalue'` in a class context is not what you expect. Besides, instance variable is `nil` by default and doesn't require explicit assignment, it is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Victor: Thanks, you're right the outer @idea was a class instance variable and never to be used, so I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

`gets` is either a `Kernel#gets` or `IO#gets` (I will omit `ARGF#gets` for brevity), `@idea` in your case is not an IO object (by default any instance variable is set to `nil`), and calling `Kernel#gets` with explicit receiver is prohibited. So correct code is `@idea = gets`.

Comment: I don't have enouhg reputation to vote up, so thank you as well.

Comment: @Hare: I did in your stead and also for pointing out the class instance variable.